# ANT global property file in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: ant, intellij-idea

How to set a global property file so that contain the defined properties are getting resolved during my ANT build in Intelliji IDEA?

In Eclipse I can do this via the "Properties" tab in the "Window/Preferences/Ant/Runtime" config.

How can I set this in Intellij IDEA 9 or 10 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDEA [allows you to specify custom properties](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/build-file-properties.html) for the build script, but not via file:

> Use this tab to specify the runtime properties that should be passed to the build script. These properties are equivalent to the ones defined after the -D option of the command line. A property is defined as a pair "name-value". The value can be hard-coded, or dynamically evaluated at runtime from a macro.

If you want to use a file, then you need to [reference properties file](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) from the build.xml:

Comment: thanks. I have big java project with about 500 build.xmls across subprojects (80 subfolders).  Every build.xml has implicit dependence on global ant properties Eclipse config.   All members of development team use Eclipse, but I wnat migrate to Intelliji IDEA. I don't want edit every build.xml and properties files, so i finding simple method to gain Eclipse-like ant global properties in IDEA.

Comment: Using IDE specific settings to manage your builds is not very portable. I'm afraid you are out of luck here.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can execute the Ant build script on the command shell (View > Tool Windows > Terminal). The command `ant` can load specific property files, e.g.: `<property file="./resources/build.properties" />`.